# Gradle build is getting failed when i tried to build a spring boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, build, spring-initializr

A problem occurred configuring root project 'Task_Manager '.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.1.1.
> Required by:
> project : > org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:3.1.1
> > No matching variant of org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.1.1 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.1.1' but:
> - Variant 'apiElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.1.1 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
> - Other compatible attribute:
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.1.1')
> - Variant 'javadocElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.1.1 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.1.1')
> - Variant 'mavenOptionalApiElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin-maven-optional:3.1.1 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
> - Other compatible attribute:
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.1.1')
> - Variant 'mavenOptionalRuntimeElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin-maven-optional:3.1.1 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
> - Other compatible attribute:
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.1.1')
> - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.1.1 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
> - Other compatible attribute:
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.1.1')
> - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.1.1 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.1.1')

Answer (score 0):

For ref: I'm using VS Code on a MacBook 2020. Using id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.13'.

I just had the same issue. I solved it by creating a `gradle.properties` file in the root of the project and adding this:

```
org.gradle.java.home=<myPathTo>openjdk@17/17.0.7/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/
```

Afterwards, I made sure that port :8080 was available, and then I succeeded running `gradle bootRun` / or executing it using the extension in VSCode.

*Between every change I did, I ran the build.clean task which made it clear for me that port 8080 was occupied.*

---

For 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.1' I followed a combination of the answer from [Vifeng](https://github.com/vifeng) in this [link](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/3094) and my answer above.